# Blazor and ContinueWith on page load

Tags: async-await, parallel-processing, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor. I'm working on a Server App (not WASM).

On a page load, I am loading 2 things to a page. Item1 is loaded at the same time as Item2 via API calls. I'd like individual items to show up as soon as they are available. I was thinking something like

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var t1 = _service.GetItem1().ContinueWith(t => {
        Item1Loaded = true;
        Item2State = t.Result;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });

    var t2 = _service.GetItem2().ContinueWith(t => {
        Item2Loaded = true;
        Item2State = t.Result;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });
}
```

I have a couple questions about this though:

1. Do I need to worry about canceling these lines if the user navigates away from the component? (would changing a state variable after the component is removed cause a problem) or does Blazor handle that at the framework level somehow?
2. Do I need to ensure this gets back to a certain thread with a Synchronization Context? It seems like `InvokeAsync` just does this for me but want to be sure.
3. Its hard to find lots of modern examples of `ContinueWith`. async/await is dominant, but I don't think it allows continuations to execute in the order they complete. Is this a reasonable use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Server side you can do this more cleanly (ContinueWith is more or less obsolete since async / await):

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(async () => 
      { Item1State = await _service.GetItem1(); 
        Item1Loaded = true; // you can probably derive this from Item1State
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
      });

    var t2 = Task.Run(async () => 
      { Item2State = await _service.GetItem2();
        Item2Loaded = true;           
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
      });

   await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
```

<strike>No need to call StateHasChanged() here.</strike>

Without the ItemLoaded guards you could do this without Task.Run().

Comment: Interesting. Does this actually allow both items to update independently, or is the page only going to load when both are complete. Say t2 takes 5 seconds and t1 takes 10 seconds?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, you did not answer the question asked by the OP: `or is the page only going to load when both are complete. Say t2 takes 5 seconds and t1 takes 10 seconds?` Suppose I'm asking you the same question... Really, does the code you provided, render the page with data for the first item (t1) after 10 seconds, and then re-render the page, after 5 seconds, when second task is completed ? Your code is wrong and it does not do what the OP wants it to do.  Could you please explain what is the purpose of  `Task.WhenAll` in your code.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: `No, on second thought you will need a StateHasChanged, in both Tasks.` May I ask why ? The code is executed in the OnInitializedAsync life-cycle method... re-rendering occurs automatically. By-design. `ContinueWith is more or less obsolete.`  Says who ?

Comment: @enet - Yes, multi-threading is hard to get your head around. The code posted here is almost a MRE, just try it out. I'm sure you'll see that my code works and all parts are essential. If you still have problems, just use the [Ask  Question] button on the top of every page here.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Both of us know pretty well who should use the [Ask Question] button. And no, your code does not do what the OP have asked: `or is the page only going to load when both are complete. Say t2 takes 5 seconds and t1 takes 10 seconds?` And you still refuse to answer me or hin this simple question. I'll post an answer to demonstrate what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to worry about canceling these lines if the user navigates away

Most modern DB stuff can be passed a cancellation token.  So, use that if you wish to cancel the operation.  If It's your own code and the operations are long running, consider using cancellation tokens.

> Do I need to ensure this gets back to a certain thread with a Synchronization Context?

Calling `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` ensures the UI code is run on the  UI thread.

> Question 3

Stick with simple `await`.  Yes, it executes in order.  And call `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` between operations to update the UI if you have more than two await operations.

Note : This will only work if you await real async code, not sync code wrapped in a Task!  If there are no yields, the Renderer gets no thread time so the UI doesn't get updated till it gets some.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I was worried that modifying state after the user navigates away from the component could lead to errors, but I haven't experienced any so far, thus I was considering cancellation. Thanks for confirming the InvokeAsync stuff. As for executing in order, it's not really an option in this case or I would have just done that.